# Is UTF-8 and the Babel package sufficient for Swedish?

Tags: babel, unicode

Me and a pal both have Macbooks with TeXShop. He writes to me in Swedish and when I render his code all the Swedish charachters go wrong on my preview PDF/screen. When I send him back the code and he re-renders the code everything turn OK for him. We both use UTF-8 encoding and the Swedish Babel package. So are these softwares machine-dependent? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Has it ever crossed your mind that if someone does not put up screen shot or code, maybe that someone has good reasons for not doing that? Of course in the best of all worlds, I would give all the information wanted.

Comment: What reasons? Too lazy to make an example that you can show the public?

Comment: did you load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`+ `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: Thanks Bernard, that fixed my problem. I already had fontenc, but lacked inputenc. Adding that fixed the problem. But this begs the question why this was no problem for my counterpart? Because I used exactly their code?

Comment: @LoveLearning Are you sure both of you have your editors set up to the same encoding?

Comment: I believe the defaul encoding in TeXshop is still AppleMac (!!!)

Comment: Yes the default is something different from UTF-8 but I switched to UTF-8 on both Macbooks in the TeXShop preferences.

Comment: @JosephWright: My guess is a different engine not a different encoding.

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate So would it now be possible to write an answer to this question? Maybe you could do it yourself if nobody else will? Would be nice to get this question summed up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is solved in the comments.